# Specific subscription not loading

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite, meteor-helper

I have a booking rental app with a list of available listings. These listing belong to the 'listing' collection and appears fine to the client on deploying.
For each of this listing I have a listing page which has a drop down menu populated by another collection 'locations' which takes the id of the listing as a parameter to filter out results specific to the listing at hand. My code works excellent on localhost but on meteor deploy even after keeping idle for ages the drop down list appears blank.

**Note**: One of the collection 'listing' appears to load fine (on deployment) so it's not a 'insecure' package or permission issue.

Publication

```
Meteor.publish('locations', function(id){
  check(id, String);
  return Locations.find({owner: id});
});
```

Router

```
Router.route("/activity/:_id", {
    name: "activityPage",
    waitOn: function () {
        return [Meteor.subscribe("singleActivity", this.params._id)];
    },
    data: function () {
        return Activities.findOne(this.params._id);
    },
    name: "activitySubmit",
    waitOn: function () {
        var someId = this.params._id;
        return [Meteor.subscribe("locations",someId)];
    }
});
```

Comment: You were talking about a publication somewhere?

Comment: @BraveKenny Ah, sorry now I see. I missed out writing the publication code. Here changed the question!

Comment: You've got two `name` and `waiton` in your code for one route...

Answer (score 0):

You have conflicting `name` and `waitOn`, but you should specify them each only once. You can combine multiple subscriptions in the `waitOn` like so

```
Router.route("/activity/:_id", {
    name: "activityPage",
    waitOn: function () {
        return [Meteor.subscribe("singleActivity", this.params._id), Meteor.subscribe("locations",this.params._id)];
    },
    data: function () {
        return Activities.findOne(this.params._id);
    }
});
```